# spring rest web service how to solve ambiguous get

Tags: spring, rest, service, get

I have a spring web service rest.

I have two get :

```
// VIEW PRODUCT DETAILS

        @RequestMapping(value="/products/{prodId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody Product productView(@PathVariable("prodId") int prodId) {
            logger.info("======= in productView (REST)");
            Product product = inventoryService.findProductById(prodId); 
            return product;
        }

         // VIEW PRODUCT DETAILS NAME

        @RequestMapping(value="/products/{prodName}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody Product productNameView(@PathVariable("prodName") String prodName) {
            logger.info("======= in  productNameView (REST)");
            Product product = inventoryService.findProductByName(prodName); 
            return product;
        }
```

I get a ambiguous message  when I do a get with

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/products/627790"
```

How can I have two different get?

Answer (score 0):

You can user query param approach:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/products/{prodId}", 
       method=RequestMethod.GET, params = "type=prodId" )

    @RequestMapping(value="/products/{prodName}", 
     method=RequestMethod.GET, params = "type=prodName")
```

Hit call using following URLs:

http://localhost:8080/rest/products/123?type=prodId"

http://localhost:8080/rest/products/456?type=prodName"

let me know it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because when the url ***/products/627790** is hit, 627790 can be treated as int as well as string. How will the `rest` know which controller to invoke?

To avoid ambiguity in your case you should use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`. URL on client side will change but code will be more readable and resolvable.

So,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/products", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Product productView(@RequestParam("prodId") int prodId) {}


@RequestMapping(value="/products", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Product productNameView(@RequestParam("prodName") String prodName) {}
```

Your urls will be:

http://localhost:8080/rest/products/prodId=627790"

http://localhost:8080/rest/products/prodName=myProduct"